# iOS: App Groups missing user default key

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsuserdefaults, today-extension

I have an App with a today extension. I created already an app group in the developer portal and created the target in my xcode project, linking the group in the capabilities for my app and today target.

So at the app side I'm saving my values like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:suite];
[prefs setObject:value forKey:key];
[prefs synchronize];
```

The suite property is the name of my group created in the developer portal. Value is a NSDictionary.

```
 NSDictionary* savedDict = [prefs objectForKey:key];
```

Calling this gives me the correct values

At the Extension Side I'm using swift and trying to get my UserDefaults like this

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.cryptochange.favorites")
let savedDict = userDefaults?.dictionary(forKey: "Favorites");
```

The problem is, that savedDict is nil.

When I print out all keys in my user defaults I see the "Favorites" key at the app side but if I'm printing out the keys in the extension, this key is missing.

Does anybody know where or what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1: 
I just recognize that it works with a debug build but not when I change the scheme to release

EDIT 2:
I just checked the documents directory of my app and see my app groups file which includes the values I saved.
When I look up at the documents dir of the extension there is no such a file. Is this works as intended? 
After I set an "test" value inside my extension code the file appears with the test value

Comment: From Apple's documentation…  `synchronize()` _"… this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to make sure:
   suite = "group.cryptochange.favorites"
   key = "Favorites"
2. You have to check Extension is a member of group app
3. You should review that "Cast type" is correct

I hope my answers are useful

Comment: Hey Tran thanks for your answer. I already checked 1 and 2. I checked also the third point. The problem is, that I didn't even see my "Favorites"-Key when I call userdefaults.dictionaryrepresentation.keys